# How to support upload on PHP installed with IIS 7.0?

Tags: php, iis, windows-7, windows-server-2008

I install PHP on IIS 7.0 at Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7. I have setup Wordpress and Joomla and config finished.
But I find I can not upload any file with PHP program but okay under ASP.NET.

I had,

- Config the every permission with write of Upload folder to **IUSR** and **IIS_USRS**
- Config the PHP.ini with **file_uploads = On**
- Setup a temp directory and config for every permission with write.  **upload_tmp_dir = "E:\Webware\PHP.Upload.Tmp"**
- Reboot IIS

But I still can not upload file via PHP program.

Comment: Maybe you're doing it wrong. Can you post the PHP code, and possibly the relevant HTML form?

Comment: I did not modify any PHP code, but download and install Joomla and Wordpress in it. They are open source webware. Joomla's Website is, www.joomla.org. And Wordpress is, Wordpress.org.

Comment: I also have this problem and it's driving me absolutely nuts.

Answer (score 1):

When you run phpinfo() what is the value of your `upload_tmp_dir`?

I'd wager your `upload_tmp_dir` variable in the [PHP] configuration section of php.ini file is being overwritten in the [WebPIChanges] configuration section, towards the end of your php.ini file...

Depending on how you installed PHP, **there may be two** `upload_tmp_dir` **variables** in your php.ini file, and if the the second one is set, it will overwrite the first.

Comment: Cheers mate.  Had this issue on a new Server 2012 R2 build with IIS and PHP.   It was the darn WebPIChanges instance of the upload_tmp_dir that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site, it may help you: http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php
Also i suggest you to don't modify upload_temp_dir